# Interaction with a running process

Tags: keyboard-events, interaction, crystal-lang

Let's have a simple example:

```
Process.run("ping", {"google.com"}) do |proc|
  proc.output.each_line { |line| puts line }
end
```

which runs a process, constantly reading its output and printing the output to stdout. Currently, when I press a key, it just appears along with the output of the running process, but I'd like to have some kind of key processing, so I would be able to manage the running process from the keyboard: stop it, or restart it with modified arguments. How to do that?

---

Or, to narrow the question down, how to make this output-input pair to be non-blocking for each other? Currently it takes one step and then waits for its counterpart to happen.

```
Process.run("ping", {"google.com"}) do |proc|
  until proc.output.closed?
    puts proc.output.gets
    puts "Got key: #{STDIN.raw &.read_char}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a terminal for interactive input is not as simple as it might seem. You can try with `STDIN.raw &.read_char`. But this is limited and likely won't get you very far.

A tool which is usually used for this is `readline`. There are Crystal bindings in the stdlib (see  [`Readline`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/Readline.html)). They're currently undocumented, but should work. You could also try https://github.com/Papierkorb/fancyline which is a pure Crystal implementation of `readline`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, `STDIN.raw &.read_char` is quite good for me, but the other problem for me here is how to make this input-output pair non-blocking for each other? I made an addition to the question to illustrate the problem.

Comment: You need to run the IO copy operation and the STDIN reader in separate fibers.

Comment: I tried this (without any success): http://ix.io/1gIT/ruby
It must be something very simple I don't get here.

Comment: You need a separate loop in both fibers.

Answer (score 1):

This examples shows how to handle STDIN and a single TCP session. This works by spawning the handlers to fibers. With [some lines more](https://github.com/pebauer68/crystal/blob/master/bash_chat.cr) you can share a bash or REPL session with multiple clients.

example 1: long running process

```
#Long running Process, here an interactive shell for example
spawn do
    begin  
    cmd = "bash -i"
    Process.run(cmd, shell: true) do | p |
         pp p
         my.bashpid = p.pid
         my.bashinputfd = p.input.dup              #get copy of current fd
         p.input.puts("exec 2>&1")                 #stderr > stdout
         p.input.puts("echo connected to bash")    #send to STDIN of bash
          while line = p.output.read_line 
            puts line                     #send to STDOUT
            #send output of shell process to all online clients
            Mc.get_clients.each do |all|  
                     all.puts (line)   #send to Client
                   end  
          end
       end 

    rescue exception
      puts "Error: #{exception.message}"
      puts "Shell process has ended, program exits"
      exit
    end
end
```

example 2:

```
require "socket"
#public vars
channel = Channel(String).new
csocket = Socket.tcp(Socket::Family::INET)
socket_conn=false
puts "Welcome:"

    spawn do
      server = TCPServer.new("0.0.0.0", 9090)
      loop do   #handle tcp client reconnects - do forever
       socket = server.accept
       csocket = socket.dup
       socket_conn=true
       p! socket_conn
       print "\r"

       while line = socket.gets
         channel.send(line)
       end
       socket_conn=false
       p! socket_conn
       print "\r"
      end
    end

    spawn do  #handle stdin input char by char - do until ctrl-c pressed
        while (char = STDIN.raw &.read_char) != '\u{3}'    #ctrl-c
        channel.send(char.to_s)
        end
        channel.send('\u{3}'.to_s)
    end

    loop do  #do until cttrl-c
      r = channel.receive
      if r == "\u0003"  #handle ctrl-c from channel
         break
      end
      p! socket_conn
      print "\r"
      p! r
      print "\r"
      if socket_conn 
           csocket.puts "got: #{r}"
      end 
      puts "got: #{r}"
      print "\r"
    end
```